# How to run exe from local disk from web browser?

Tags: web, exe, webclient

I have requirement to open .EXE which is store on client local disk through web browser. It should cross browser compatible. What is the way to achieve this scenario? Is there any plug-in for the same?

Comment: Can I ask why my answer is not acceptable for you?

Comment: sorry your answer is acceptable. I guess my question was not popper to understand. But now i am able to open .exe from browser simply using using System.Diagnostics;  ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("app.exe"); Process.Start(startInfo); but its not cross browser compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to run an EXE file from a webpage due to security limitations. In older versions of IE that was possible using ActiveX plugins.

You could do it using a remote access software such as Ammyy admin or TeamViewer, but you'll need the client's consent. If it is your EXE file you want to run, consider switching to HTML 5/Java/flash/Silverlight based application, which can be embedded in websites.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your operating system and wether you control your client machines, or not. Browsers generally do their best to prevent this kind of stuff for security purposes.

If you control the clients, you should look into custom URI handlers. Example for windows [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).